# Tweepy - Exclude retweets using .usertimeline

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to all of a specific account's tweets to a CSV. I have the below working correctly but now I'm trying to exclude retweets from what is being pulled in .usertimeline

```
alltweets = []
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)

alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

#save the id of the oldest tweet less one
oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

while len(new_tweets) > 0:
    #print "getting tweets before %s" % (oldest)
    print("getting tweets before %s" % (oldest))

    #all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)


    #save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    #update the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    print("...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets)))

#transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv
outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.replace('\n',' ').encode('utf-8'), tweet.retweet_count, tweet.favorite_count, tweet.retweeted] for tweet in alltweets]
```

I've tried using the below but have no solution so far. I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

```
for tweet in outtweets:
    if ('RT @' not in tweet.text):
#write the csv
        with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'w') as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text", "retweet_count", "favorite_count", "retweeted"])
            writer.writerows(outtweets)

pass
```

Comment: outtweets is a list of lists, so for tweet in outtweets makes tweet a list, and as the error tells you lists don't have a text attribute. You should filter alltweets, which doesn't contain lists, or alter your code to actually deal with a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each item in outtweets is a list with the following attributes :

```
0 - id_str
1 - created_at
2 - tweet_text
3 - retweet_count
4 - favorite_count
5 - retweeted
```

It is tweet[2] you want from what I see here. So you should use :

```
#write the csv
 with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'w') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text", "retweet_count", "favorite_count", "retweeted"])
   for tweet in outtweets:
     if ('RT @' not in tweet[2]):
        writer.writerow(tweet)
```

Comment: That makes sense. I tried using the above but i get an error ```TypeError: 'Status' object is not subscriptable```. It says in other threads it describes objects that are "containers". How can i get around this?

Comment: My bad. You need to replace writer.writerows(outtweets) with writer.writerows(tweet)

Comment: I have edited the code. This is what you were trying to do I guess.